# Get first line in textbox c#

Tags: c#

c#
I need to get the first line on a multi line text.box

every time I try this I get the whole textbox

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 11):

Use the TextBox.[Lines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.lines.aspx) property which is a string[] array representing the lines of text:

```
textBox.Lines.Count > 0 ? textBox.Lines[0] : null
```

or alternatively (and shorter):

```
textBox.Lines.FirstOrDefault()
```

Comment: I like this one. It's just as correct as Max Malygin's answer, but safer.

Comment: This is only the WinForms implementation since the Lines property is only available there. My answer below works for ASP.NET, WinForms and WPF. Carefully: in WPF you have a LineCount property but I assume this is layout information, so lines that are wrapped are also counted there.

Answer (score 5):

```
myTextBox.Text.Split(Environment.NewLine).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
yourtextbox.Lines[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

if you split the text by \n character you will get the text as line by line as a string array. The first index of the array is the first row of your multine textbox. for example:

```
string firstLine = TextBox1.Text.Split('\n')[0];
```

This is for textbox in asp.net controls. If you want to obtain the same thing in a windows form application, you should write example code above:

```
string firstLine = textBox1.Lines[0];
```